# Laravel 5.1 PhpUnit Delete method not working

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I am writing a simple test to create an element, see if it is there and then delete it to verify the integrity of my web app every time I build it.

I have a test:

```
$this->visit('admin/menu/samples')
        ->seePageIs('admin/menu/samples')
        ->click('New Sample')
        ->seePageIs('admin/menu/samples/new/create')
        ->type('test1', 'name')
        ->type('test2','description')
        ->type('test2','introduction')
        ->select(1, 'scenario_id')
        ->type('test','slug')
        ->press('Add')
        ->seePageIs('admin/menu/samples')
        ->delete('admin/menu/samples/'. \App\Sample::whereSlug('test')->first()->id )
        ->visit('admin/menu/samples')
        ->dontSee('test1');
```

it creates the Sample element fine, but as I have several Delete buttons ( for every Sample element in index, as they are in a list) I can't use the method click/press('Delete'). So I thought I'd just use the delete method, which I have already set up. The problem is that it will not delete the element that I have created. The delete request will not work.
I assure you that the route is there and the if I just press the Delete button my Sample element will be deleted.

Why can't I mimic this with PHPUnit, is there another way to delete?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same exact issue. Turns out its the CSRF token issue. Anytime you do a request other than the "GET" request, you will need to verify your CSRF token. Now Laravel does a good job already doing this when you are on the website itself, which is why submitting forms via "press" will work: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection. In my specific case, it seems my token is generated via an XSRF-Token cookie, which can be done via a simple check of the Request Headers.

However, if you use the url, you will need to generate a CSRF token manually. To do this, simply call `csrf_token()` and inject it into your call:

```
$this->visit('admin/menu/samples')
    ...
    ->delete('admin/menu/samples/'. \App\Sample::whereSlug('test')->first()->id,
                ['_token'=>csrf_token()],[] )
    ...;
```

Here was the article that helped me figure out how to inject the token, though dont confuse the method signatures of $this->call and $this->delete:
http://davejustdave.com/2015/02/08/laravel-5-unit-testing-with-csrf-protection/

Comment: haha thanks, I made a work around like.
-delete>(\App\Sample::whereSlug('test')->first()-delete()). not the best one though, but worked. Thanks anyhow, now I know how to do it correctly